# sequenced builds in RTC/Jazz

Tags: build, rtc, jazz

we have some depending builds, and i want to start them all after all... (talking of RTC/Jazz build definition, which are used in RTC/Jazz source control - we use the build-engine from RTC/Jazz)

1. build framework
2. build server [depends on 1.]
3. build (start) unit test server [depends on 2.]
4. build client [depends on 1.]
5. build (start) unit test client [depends on 4.]
6. build (generate) allover report [depends on 1.-5.]
7. build (publish) if all was ok... [depends on 6. if ok]

is there a way to add a sequence into different build definitions? the builds are performed on two different build engines which are even on different build server. right now i have to copy the results and publish all manually...

one important note: these are the nightly builds, where all work of the day is brought together... they are triggered via the 'schedule option' in each build definition. but think what happens when one build is not yet ready and the other already starts? (this already has happened and i want to avoid it furthermore)...

what is the proper way to handle this? (maybe i was using the search option wrong but no results in google and Stackoverflow)

[image]

Comment: Just FYI, if you don't get any responses from here, you can check out the [Jazz.net forums](https://jazz.net/forum) to get support directly from IBMers. Source: I used to be a developer on the Jazz platform.

Comment: well thanks, i'll reagrd this - although i know of the user VonC (http://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) which was very often a great help on Stoackoverflow @MarcBaumbach

Comment: I am still commuting, and I am on my phone

Comment: Hello VonC - this is not an urgend question, so please don't feel under pressure @VonC

Comment: And... back to work.

Answer (score 2):

The build scheduler management in RTC isn't as complete as a TeamCity or Jenkins (actually, RTC4+ allows to delegate that job scheduling feature to Jenkins)

But if you want to introduce a sequence between builds definitions, you can look at post-build delivery, introduced in "[How to keep your streams flowing smoothly in Rational Team Concert 3.0.1](https://jazz.net/library/article/649)".
The idea is, if a build succeeds, to trigger a deliver to another stream ([post-build deliver step](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.build.doc/topics/tcreatebuilddefinition.html&scope=null)).
If that other stream is monitored by another job, that job would only starts if the previous one succeeds: sequence achieved.

This seems simpler than [adding pre/post-build extensions points](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/23182/creating-custom-pre-build-and-post-build-options).

Note that post-build steps [currently don't get run when a build is invoked by the Team Concert Plugin for Jenkins](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/134626/build-definition-post-build-deliver?page=1&focusedAnswerId=135047#135047). See [WI 277270](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=277270).

Comment: ok, i understand your approch... but this requires a deliver option wich is not liked among my people... i must consider this way, it really seems to be working that way (i konw of the postbuild-options and triggering, so thank you already - but this is not what i was expecting, and thus it may take some time to find it out)

Comment: "deliver option wich is not liked among my people": I am not sure I follow: this is an automatic deliver here.

Comment: hehe - whenever you deliver a change set from one stream to another all repository workspaces (with flow target that stream) receive that changeset as pending change... maybe i must set up the streams in another way...

Comment: or i must tell them how to setup their repository workspaces in a different way...

Comment: give me some time to think about it, because i think that you showed me again a possible solution - but i'm not that fast, so forgive me please ^^

Comment: @MartinFrank no, you deliver to another **stream dedicated for the next build**, not to a stream monitored by people! Nobody receive notifications if they don't have to.

Comment: ok, i understand - but making another stream where we already have so many streams - i've attached a screenshot to my question, so i really have to think oabut that first a little - still i'm thinking that looks like you told me the right approach!

Comment: @MartinFrank you don't have to make another stream in the same project area. You can have a dedicated build project area, with streams dedicated to your build sequence, reusing components from the first project area. That helps keep the stream cluttering to an acceptable level.

Comment: i don't have the rights to do so, i must first ask for permission to create such an project - still i think i can create private streams for that purpose... as mentioned above you showed me a good way to do make sequenced build possible... i just need some time to think this whole thing through!!

Answer (score 1):

You can place a post request to jour jazz server after each successful build like:
localhost:/jazz/service/com.ibm.team.build.internal.common.ITeamBuildRequestService

```
<request>
<method>requestBuild2</method>
<interface>com.ibm.team.build.internal.common.ITeamBuildRequestService</interface>
<parameters xsi:type="com.ibm.team.repository.common.services:ComplexDataArg">
    <type>COMPLEX</type>
    <value xsi:type="build:BuildRequestParams">
        <allowDuplicateRequests>true</allowDuplicateRequests>
        <personalBuild>false</personalBuild>
        <buildDefinition  itemId="YOUR_BUILD_DEFINITION_NAME" />
    </value>
</parameters>
</request>
```

Comment: that sounds interesting - where exactly do i have to extend my requestService (sorry, i'm quite new to this topic, so don't be embarresed)

Comment: It is very similar to the action performed via Web UI: login, post your build request, and afterwards poll every 30 or 60 sec for the result.

Comment: ok, i see how to do it... this seems to be another good solution, so there is even more to consider now ^^ give me some time, but i like this solution as well!